# converting a curl to a fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm looking at this influx documentation (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/querying_data/) on the api and I can run a curl like this:

```
curl -G 'http://10.111.11.11:9050/query?db=sdp_metrics' --data-urlencode "q=select distinct(host) from jmx where time > now() - 180m"
```

I'm trying to convert that structure to a fetch in reactjs but can't seem to get it to work. In react, I have this:

```
return fetch('http://10.111.11.11:9050/query?db=sdp_metrics&q=' + 'select distinct(host) from jmx where time > now() - 180m'
            ).then(infltest => { does stuff })
```

the browser comes back with a 200 but I don't get any data back.

Comment: If my answer isn't correct, could you clarify if this is a GET or POST request? (curl noob)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'http://10.111.11.11:9050/query?db=sdp_metrics&q=' 
  + encodeURIComponent('select distinct(host) from jmx where time > now() - 180m')
```